# Filter out Temporary Files from a Directory.GetFiles List C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to only keep files with the file extensions .SLDPRT, .SLDASM, and .SLDDRW.  However, I keep getting hidden temporary files that begin with ~$ like C:\directory\~$IamAtemporaryfile.sldprt .  What are your suggestions to get rid of those?

```
string[] solidworksFileList = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.SLD???", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(str => str.EndsWith(".SLDPRT", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || str.EndsWith(".SLDASM", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || str.EndsWith(".SLDDRW", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another where to ignore files starting with ~$

```
string[] solidworksFileList = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.SLD???", 
SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(str => str.EndsWith(".SLDPRT", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || str.EndsWith(".SLDASM", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || str.EndsWith(".SLDDRW", 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.Where(str => !str.Contains(@"\~$")
.ToArray();
```

Comment: This is close.  However, GetFiles returns the full path.  So Where(str => !str.Contains(@"\~$") is better.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can simplify your logic with a `HashSet`:

```
readonly HashSet<string> AllowedExtensions = new HashSet<string>(
    { ".SLDPRT", ".SLDASM", ".SLDDRW" },
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

and in your method that gets the files:

```
string[] solidworksFileList = Directory.GetFiles(args[0], "*.SLD???",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(str => AllowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(str)) &&
                  !Path.GetFileName(str).StartsWith("~$"))
    .ToArray();
```

This would be a more general solution in that you could add any number of extensions to the `HashSet` and lookup would still be near constant time. And it's a whole lot easier than typing an arbitrarily large number of `str.EndsWith` conditionals.